# Genexus EV3 + Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, genexus

Olá, tenho um projeto no qual sempre utilizei o Tomcat 7, e sempre funcionou sem problemas. Porém, quando solicitado que eu executasse o projeto com o Tomcat 8 as páginas retornam o erro 404.

Nos logs to Tomcat apontam isso:

> 03-Jun-2015 15:32:40.512 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw exception
>    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.genexus.webpanels.GXJarScanner
>   ...

Não sei se pode ser problema com Tomcat ou a compatibilidade, no caso, utilizo a 64 bits.

Peço que me ajudem com esse problema, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Isso parece ser um problema de classpath na configuração da sua aplicação. Acho que não tem a ver com o fato de ser 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma atualização para o GXJarScanner que deveria resolver esse problema. 
Pode pegá-lo desde aqui: 
http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,8,77,O,E,0,,4458